# Upsert Data with dataLoader using multiple keys

Tags: data-loader, upsert, data-import-wizard, data-import

Is there a way to import Data with DataLoader \ Wizard using 2 keys?

For example - I want to import Data (Upsert) when the unique key is actually built from 2 keys :

externalId field and a recordTypeId.

---

Account 1 :

ExternaliD: 111

RecordtypeId: 222

---

Account 2:

ExternaliD: 111

RecordtypeId: 333

---

Now I cant UPSERT the data only with the externalId field because it's not unique, But the recordttypeId and the ExternalId **together** are unique

How can I achieve it? (**Without creating a new field and concatenate  the field and the recordType**)

Thanks!

Comment: u want to upsert it to a record rt?

Comment: Hi I just edited the question..

Comment: Hi u can do two uploads based on recordtypeId..